# How to transform Vim configuration into Emacs one?

Tags: vim, emacs, text-editor, vimrc

I need to setup Emacs editor by preparing the `~/.emacs` configuration file. I have been using Vim for years and now I want to switch to Emacs for various reasons that are out of scope of this post. To do so, I need to reproduce in Emacs all the functionality of Vim that I worked out over years of using it. In other words: **I want to transform my `~/.vimrc` configuration file into the equivalent `~/.emacs` configuration file**. I include my `~/.vimrc` with all settings commented in this post.

I know that my `~/.vimrc` contains quite a lot of settings, but I have already figured out how transform some of them, and I am also aware that some of the settings don't really need to be transformed. Unfortunately, most of them are still beyond my current knowledge of Emacs configuration.

Here is my `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Configuration file for Vi Improved, save as ~/.vimrc to use.
set nocompatible " Vim mode instead of pure Vi
set encoding=utf-8 " encoding used for displaying file
set fileencoding=utf-8 " encoding used when saving file
set nobackup " do not keep the backup~ file
set confirm " confirm :q in case of unsaved changes
set ruler " show the cursor position all the time
set textwidth=80 " wrap lines automatically at 80th column
set tabstop=8 " set tabulator length to 8 columns
set expandtab " fill tabs with spaces
set softtabstop=8 " backspacing over 8 spaces like over tabs
set shiftwidth=8 " set indentation depth to 8 columns
set backspace=indent,eol,start " backspacing over everything in insert mode
set nojoinspaces " no extra space after '.' when joining lines
set incsearch " do incremental search
set ignorecase " do case insensitive search...
set smartcase " ...unless capital letters are used
set hlsearch " highlight search results
set showmatch " highlight matching braces

filetype on " enable file type detection
filetype plugin on " load the plugins for specific file types
filetype indent on " automatically indent code...
set cinoptions=:0g0 " ...but don't indent case labels and access modifiers

syntax enable " syntax highlighting
set background=dark " dark background for console
colorscheme solarized " set color scheme, must be installed before use

" characters for displaying non-printable characters
set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:.,nbsp:_,extends:+,precedes:+

" tuning for gVim only
if has('gui_running')
    set number " show line numbers
    set columns=84 lines=48 " GUI window geometry
    set guifont=Monospace\ 12 " font for GUI window
    set background=light " light background for GUI
endif

" automatic commands
if has('autocmd')
    " file type specific automatic commands

    " don't replace Tabs with spaces when editing makefiles
    autocmd Filetype makefile setlocal noexpandtab

    " press F5 to call `indent` for C and C++ source code files
    autocmd FileType c,cpp noremap <F5> :%!indent -kr -brf -nut<cr>
    autocmd FileType c,cpp inoremap <F5> <Esc>:%!indent -kr -brf -nut<cr>

    " tuning textwidth for Java code
    autocmd FileType java setlocal textwidth=132
    if has('gui_running')
        autocmd FileType java setlocal columns=136
    endif

    " disable automatic code indentation when editing TeX and XML files
    autocmd FileType tex,xml setlocal indentexpr=

    " clean-up commands that run automatically on write; use with caution

    " delete empty or whitespaces-only lines at the end of file
    autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\(\s*\n\)\+\%$//ge

    " replace groups of empty or whitespaces-only lines with one empty line
    autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\(\s*\n\)\{3,}/\r\r/ge

    " delete any trailing whitespaces
    autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//ge
endif

" general key mappings

" center view on the search result
noremap n nzz
noremap N Nzz

" press F4 to fix indentation in whole file; overwrites marker 'q' position
noremap <F4> mqggVG=`qzz
inoremap <F4> <Esc>mqggVG=`qzza

" press F8 to turn the search results highlight off
noremap <F8> :nohl<cr>
inoremap <F8> <Esc>:nohl<cr>a 

" press F12 to toggle showing the non-printable charactes
noremap <F12> :set list!<cr>
inoremap <F12> <Esc>:set list!<cr>a
```

Comment: Ask the emacs help list if you don't get an answer here: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-gnu-emacs

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no automated way to do this.  Have you have probably made progress and/or no longer need this answer?

Your question isn't very specific. You mention you have already figured out a lot of your conversion, and some don't need to be transformed. Which still do?

There is a vim mode for emacs [called evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) that might be interesting. They have a youtube [video](http://youtu.be/Uz_0i27wYbg) too.